# Images Not Showing After Saving/Sending to Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to make a chat app, but i'm facing a problem. When i'm trying to upload a profile image and then store it in the firebase. The said image that i've uploaded always stored in the firebase, but the image is not showing in the app, only a blank white screen. This problem exists in every image-firebase related stuff in my project (because i keep reusing the same code over and over again). What's my mistake(s)? Is there's something i miss or did it wrong? Any kinds of help is welcome.

I've attached some of my code and screenshot that might be related to my problem

1. ProfileActivity

private final String TAG = "CA/ProfileActivity";

```
// // Will handle all changes happening in database

private DatabaseReference userDatabase, requestsDatabase, friendsDatabase;
private ValueEventListener userListener, requestsListener, friendsListerner;

// Users data

private String currentUserId, otherUserId;

// activity_profile views

private TextView name, status;
private CircleImageView image;
private KenBurnsView cover;
private FABsMenu menu;
private TitleFAB button1, button2, button3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

    name = findViewById(R.id.profile_name);
    status = findViewById(R.id.profile_status);
    image = findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
    menu = findViewById(R.id.profile_fabs_menu);
    cover = findViewById(R.id.profile_cover);

    otherUserId = getIntent().getStringExtra("userid");
    currentUserId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
}

@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();

    if(userDatabase != null && userListener != null)
    {
        userDatabase.removeEventListener(userListener);
    }

    // Initialize/Update realtime user data such as name, email, status, image

    userDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(otherUserId);
    userDatabase.keepSynced(true); // For offline use
    userListener = new ValueEventListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            try
            {
                String layoutName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                String layoutStatus = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();
                final String layoutImage = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();
                final String layoutCover = dataSnapshot.child("cover").getValue().toString();

                name.setText(layoutName);
                status.setText("\"" + layoutStatus + "\"");

                if(!layoutImage.equals("default"))
                {
                    Picasso.get()
                            .load(layoutImage)
                            .resize((int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 180, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()), (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 180, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()))
                            .centerCrop()
                            .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
                            .placeholder(R.drawable.user)
                            .error(R.drawable.user)
                            .into(image, new Callback()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess()
                                {

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onError(Exception e)
                                {
                                    Picasso.get()
                                            .load(layoutImage)
                                            .resize((int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 180, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()), (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 180, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()))
                                            .centerCrop()
                                            .placeholder(R.drawable.user)
                                            .error(R.drawable.user)
                                            .into(image);
                                }
                            });

                    image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view)
                        {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, FullScreenActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("imageUrl", layoutImage);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.user);
                }

                if(!layoutCover.equals("default"))
                {
                    Picasso.get()
                            .load(layoutCover)
                            .resize(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels, (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 260, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()))
                            .centerCrop()
                            .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
                            .placeholder(R.drawable.logo_cover)
                            .error(R.drawable.logo_cover)
                            .into(cover, new Callback()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess()
                                {

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onError(Exception e)
                                {
                                    Picasso.get()
                                            .load(layoutCover)
                                            .resize(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels, (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 260, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()))
                                            .centerCrop()
                                            .placeholder(R.drawable.logo_cover)
                                            .error(R.drawable.logo_cover)
                                            .into(cover);
                                }
                            });
                }
                else
                {
                    cover.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo_cover);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "userDatabase listener exception: " + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "userDatabase listener failed: " + databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    };
    userDatabase.addValueEventListener(userListener);

    if(otherUserId.equals(currentUserId))
    {
        initMyProfile();
    }
    else
    {
        initOtherProfile();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(currentUserId).child("online").setValue("true");
}

@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();

    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(currentUserId).child("online").setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
}

@Override
protected void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();

    removeListeners();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        Uri url = data.getData();

        //Uploading selected picture

        StorageReference file = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("profile_images").child(currentUserId + ".jpg");
        file.putFile(url).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task)
            {
                if(task.isSuccessful())
                {
                    String imageUrl = task.getResult().toString();

                    // Updating image on user data

                    userDatabase.child("image").setValue(imageUrl).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
                        {
                            if(task.isSuccessful())
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Picture updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Log.d(TAG, "updateImage listener failed: " + task.getException().getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "uploadImage listener failed: " + task.getException().getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else if(requestCode == 2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        Uri url = data.getData();

        //Uploading selected cover picture

        StorageReference file = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("profile_covers").child(currentUserId + ".jpg");
        file.putFile(url).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task)
            {
                if(task.isSuccessful())
                {
                    String imageUrl = task.getResult().toString();

                    // Updating image on user data

                    userDatabase.child("cover").setValue(imageUrl).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
                        {
                            if(task.isSuccessful())
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Cover updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Log.d(TAG, "updateUserCover listener failed: " + task.getException().getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "uploadCover listener failed: " + task.getException().getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

2. FullscreenActivity

public class FullScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_screen);

```
    final String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("imageUrl");

    final ImageView image= findViewById(R.id.a_fullscreen_image);
    final TextView message = findViewById(R.id.a_fullscreen_message);

    message.setText("Loading Picture...");
    message.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    Picasso.get()
            .load(url)
            .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
            .into(image, new Callback()
            {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess()
                {
                    message.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Exception e)
                {
                    Picasso.get()
                            .load(url)
                            .into(image, new Callback()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess()
                                {
                                    message.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onError(Exception e)
                                {
                                    message.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    message.setText("Error: Could not load picture.");
                                }
                            });
                }
            });

}
```

}

3. Firebase rules

[firebase rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FkBI.png)

4. The aforementioned problem in the app

[the output for the fullscreen activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnEHw.png)

[the output for the chat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNU9D.png)
(images supposed to be showing)

[the output for the profile activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOhPH.png)
(the profile picture supposed to be different image that i uploaded earlier not the default one)

5. [Stored images in firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGyCP.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the data through Intent. Print the layoutImage in logcat and check Whether the link is there or not.

Most used method is you can fetch the profile image link directly in your full screen activity and add it to your picasso code. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

I used Glide for fetching images from firebase and displaying in profile, it worked fine.

```
Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(imagePath).into(profileImage);
```

Comment: Do i need to include new dependencies for that?

Comment: yes , add this in your app level build.gradle `implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'`